# Lean to wood shed

Tags: framing

building a 10×24 lean to wood shed / maybe chicken run, I misjudged the slope of hill, wanted to gain another 1 1/2 inches of height to get a little more pitch, right now my beams are 2 2×6 s giving me 5 1/2 inches on top of my posts , could I secure 2x4 on top giving my meam height 7 inches or is that a structure no no? Thank you in advance for any feedback on this.

Comment: The you are planning is okay, laying the 2x4 flat and nailing/screwing into both 2x6.

Comment: It's a shed - in most (not all) jurisdictions you're free to build it as you like and take the consequences if you make a bad guess. Nothing obviously wrong with the proposed approach, though more slope is perhaps most easily gotten by trimming the low-side posts, and structure-wise using 2x8's would do more than adding a 2x4, but if 2x6 is adequate then that's not needed, and it sounds like you already have them in place.

Comment: Thank you, ecnerwal I didn't word that quite right I also wanted to gain some height. Thanks for responses